# How to get dropdonwlist content on selction of another dropdownlist in asp .net

Tags: asp.net

Dependent drop down list behavior implementation in asp .net

There are two dropdownlist
when someone select value from one drop down list On SelectedIndexChanged values from other dropdownlist needs to be changed. Any way to do it without page refresh like ajax. Can we avoid even database call by filling all values.

Mean say first dropdownlist is States and other is cities. When user select state without database call cities in that state only visible.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can populate one dropdownlist on the basis of another by binding one dropdownlist with other

You can find link to useful resource as below

[Populating dropdown list based on selection in another](http://www.aspdotnet-suresh.com/2010/10/how-to-populate-dropdown-based-on-other.html)